# why cake php framework not recognize true syntax in this example

Tags: cakephp, controller

why cake PHP framework not recognize true syntax in this example

1. User has Many Photos
2. Photos belongs to User

In User Model

```
var $hasMany = array( 'Photo' => array( 'className' => 'Photo', 'foreignKey' => 'user_id' );
```

In Photo Model

```
var $belongsTo = array( 'user' => array( 'className' => 'User', 'foreignKey' => 'user_id', 'conditions' => '', 'fields' => '', 'order' => '' ), 'PhotoAlbum' => array( 'className' => 'PhotoAlbum', 'foreignKey' => 'photo_album_id', 'conditions' => '', 'fields' => '', 'order' => '', ))
```

in Photo controller , in add action cake generate this code :

```
$this->Photo->User->find('all');
```

but true code is :

```
$this->Photo->user->find('all');
```

means user property should upper case but cake not recognize and bake false code.

Comment: In every cake app I've every worked with, `$this->Photo->User->find('all');` is the correct example. Why do you say the "true code" should be `$this->Photo->user`?

Comment: because by correct example cake show this error 
Undefined property:  User::$Photo [APP\controllers\students_Photo.php, line 29]

Comment: your controller name is not in line with the cake conventions..you should clarify and post more relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also - the problem isn't cake. The problem is you have a var $name = "user"; in your user model.

Name your model with the cake conventions correctly and this won't happen. When you don't follow conventions you run into problems with the framework. The correct solution is to read the manual instead of posting questions with near worthless debug info here @ SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up the $uses var. In your case in the photos_controller:

```
$var uses = array('User');
```

Answer (score 0):

i find that when happen my problem , this error happen when I use association in my class and i use uppercase name for user in my code of photo model's

```
var $belongsTo = array( 'user' => array( 'className' => 'User', 'foreignKey' => user_id', 'conditions' => '', 'fields' => '', 'order' => '' ), 'PhotoAlbum' => array( 'className' => 'PhotoAlbum', 'foreignKey' => 'photo_album_id', 'conditions' => '', 'fields' => '', 'order' => '', ))
```

but user is true with Under spelling (***User***)

```
var $belongsTo = array( 'User' ...
```